# MySQL Workbench não inicia

Tags: mysql

Tenho trabalhado diariamente no mysql workbench. Acontece que do nada, a ferramenta deixou de funcionar. Carrego no ícone e não acontece nada. Já tentei reiniciar o computador assim como reiniciar o serviço "MySQL56" mas sem efeito.

Fui consultar o ficheiro wb em "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log\wb" e tem o seguinte erro: "Workbench]: Console redirection failed."

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isto?

Comment: Pedro, tente adicionar mais detalhes a sua pergunta. Acontece algum erro quando tu abre o programa?

Comment: Já tentou desinstalar o programa e instalar novamente? E na verdade acho que essa pergunta não é sobre programação.... Acho que deveria ter um Super User em Português para esse tipo de pergunta.

Comment: Não tem um arquivo de logs para o MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Pela linha de comando vc consegue acesso? qual versão workbench está usando?

Comment: Pela linha de comandos consigo aceder ao mysql. Mas acho mais prático trabalhar com o mysql workbench. Quando tento abrir o programa não aparece nada. Fui consultar a pasta de logs e tem o seguinte erro: "Workbench]: Console redirection failed".

Answer (score 4):

Como descobrir e reportar os bugs do MySQL Workbench:

```
# Microsoft Windows
shell> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.3.4\"
shell> MySQLWorkbench.exe -log-level=debug3

# OS X
shell> cd /Applications
shell> MySQLWorkbench --log-level=debug3

# Linux (Ubuntu)
shell> cd /usr/bin
shell> mysqlworkbench --log-level=debug3
```

Diretórios de criação dos logs:

```
Windows 7:

C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log

OSX: 

~/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/logs

Linux: 

~/.mysql/workbench/logs
```

Referência:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-reporting-bugs.html

Comment: Na pasta do log, abri o ficheiro "wb" e contêm o seguinte erro: "Workbench]: Console redirection failed".

Comment: Se você entende inglês esses sites podem ajudar: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70262, https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70474

Comment: Sim segundo uma das respostas a solução passa por : "the problem is fixed, I just renamed the folder 
"C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench" that was previously created by an earlier used version".  Devo dar um novo nome à pasta Workbench? Já tentei fazê-lo mas não resutou em nada...

Comment: Veja a resposta do Steve, resultou segundo os comentários. Deletou um arquivo SQL de 0k, não sei se pode ser seu caso também.